# Filling subplot with colormap - Matplotlib LogNorm does work in python 3 anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I had pretty nice plots looking like this created a while ago in python 2.7.

[image]

Now it appears that LogNorm does not work anymore.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        
# creating logspaced values for colorbar
x = np.logspace(-8,-3,6)
yarr = np.vstack((x,))
print(yarr)

# check if yarr is really logspaced
ax.plot(yarr, [1e1]*len(yarr), 'w.-')

# fill box with colorbar - this does not work anymore
ax.imshow(yarr, extent=(1e-8, 1e-3, 1, 1e4), norm=LogNorm(vmin=1e-8, vmax=1e-3))


ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_yscale("log")
```

Output now

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out to me that it is a problem of matplotlib:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7661/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tmp = np.arange(199).reshape(1, 199)
y = np.logspace(0, -4, 2)
x = np.logspace(-8, -3, 200)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.pcolormesh(x, y, tmp)

plt.show()
```

This solves the problem.